# Use material2 snackbar as error handler for angular2

Tags: angular, material-design

I'm trying to set snackbar from material2 as error catcher for angular2 services. Seems to me I did everything correct but still getting an error

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'notify' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'notify' of undefined

This is my services with my catcher:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {MdSnackBar, MdSnackBarConfig, MdSnackBarRef} from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()

export class AppServices {

  private api = 'app/endpoint';
  private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  private options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private snackbar: MdSnackBar
  ) { }

  getConfigs(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.api + "/confs")
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Array<Object>)
      .catch(this.handleError)
  }

  // ==============
  // errors handler
  // ==============

  notify (status: any, text: any) {
    this.snackbar.open(status, text, {
      duration: 3000
    });
  }

  public handleError(error: Response) {
    this.notify(error.status, error.statusText);
    return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

So when catcher gets an error instead of snakebar I get the error in console that my function is undefined.

Could somebody explain me where my mistake is? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried: `.catch((err)=>{this.handleError(err);})`?

Comment: wow! it works! I appreciate if you could explain it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are losing scope within your `.catch()` statement. When the asynchronous  `.catch()` method was executing, it is attaching it's own scope to `this`.

Using an arrow function like so:

```
.catch((err)=>{this.handleError(err);})
```

Will ensure that your scope is maintained through the asynchronous method calls and typically good practice these days with TS to avoid `this` hell.

The arrow function syntax uses “lexical scoping” to figure out what the value of `this` should be. Lexical scoping is fancy way of saying it uses `this` from the surrounding code.

If you're interested in reading more about arrow functions and lexical scoping, [this is a good article](https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/).

> The interesting thing to note is that the `this` value (internally) is
>   not actually bound to the arrow function. Normal functions in
>   JavaScript bind their own `this` value, however the `this` value used in
>   arrow functions is actually fetched lexically from the scope it sits
>   inside. It has no `this`, so when you use this you’re talking to the
>   outer scope.